# Remove all products from wishlist for all customers

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

How can I remove all products from wishlist for all customers at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to delete all wishlist items associated with a particular user? ...

```
$customercollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->getCollection();
foreach($customercollection as $customer){
     $itemCollection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
     ->addCustomerIdFilter($$customer->getId());        
     foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
       $item->delete();
     }
}
```

If you want to remove all customer then you have to write one more foreach for fetching Customer.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove it for all customers

Comment: this is for one customer give me 10 min

Comment: I have update my answers please look into that